# Can't we tell which is which by sound (effect, affect)?

Tags: pronunciation

> “We’ve adjusted for lots of other things that we know **effect**
>   children’s development and IQ.”

LOE has the “effect” in its transcript above. But the audio from the same page has the sound of /əˈfɛkt/ [(2:22~2:28)](http://www.loe.org/shows/segments.html?programID=10-P13-00005&segmentID=3). Then is this the schwa pronunciation of /ɪˈfɛkt/ ? If yes, can’t we tell which word is which just by sound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, yes. But it will only be easy if the words are spoken in isolation with an effortful clarity.

But in natural speech there is a high degree of variation in vowel pronunciation: both random variation and systematic variation between speakers and linguistic contexts. You might be able to settle the question you are posing conclusively if you already had a large corpus of transcribed speech for the speaker in question, so that we could assign a probability of the word being *effect* vs. *affect*.

In practice, this is completely impractical, and the thing to do is assume that the speaker is using the prescribed form here, *affect*. But for what its worth, I am hearing the speaker say [əˈfɛkt], which is how I pronounce *affect*. I would have expected a higher vowel, but still centralized (i.e.,
 [ɨˈfɛkt]) if she was saying *effect*.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that pronunciation will tell you which word the speaker meant. After all, innumerable American speakers pronounce *marry*, *merry*, and *Mary* the same, just as they pronounce *pin* and *pen* the same and *affect* and *effect* the same.

In the sentence you quote, context tells us that it has to be *[affect](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affect?show=0&t=1357260397)* (*influence*) and not *[effect](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effect)* (*cause* or *determine*).

Answer (score 3):

In *my* (Southern UK) speech, I often (read, *usually*) use a schwa for *affect*.

But I pronounce *effect* as "if-fect" (rarely, "ef-fect", for emphasis/clarity), never with a schwa unless I'm not thinking fast enough to know which one I meant to say.